# How to load a class which extended from a form and interface?

Tags: c#, interface, casting, extend

I have few forms class which extended based Form and my custom interface.

```
Interface InterfaceForms{
      void InterfaceFunc1();
}



public partial class child1 : Form, InterfaceForms
    {
      public child1(){}
      public InterfaceFunc1(){}
    }

public partial class child2 : Form, InterfaceForms
    {
      public child2(){}
      public InterfaceFunc1(){}
    }
```

I added all the form classes object to a list as below:

```
 List<Form> lsf = new List<Form>();
```

then I tried to load the my form classes as below:

```
 var fr = from Form item in lsf
                         where item.Name == "child1"
                         select item;
Form frm = (Form)fr;
```

Now, my problem is I cannot access to InterfaceFunc1().

Would you mind advising me how I can implement this? Please take note that frm type might be diffrent each time (child1, child2 & etc) but all of them are extended from Form and InterfaceForm.

Comment: Yeah, because `Form` doesn't implement `InterfaceForms`, so actually you need to have a `List<InterfaceForms>` in order to call the function on the item of that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it as `InterfaceForms`:

```
var fr = from Form item in lsf
                         where item.Name == "child1"
                         select item;
Form frm = (Form)fr;
var iFaceFrm = frm as InterfaceForms;

if (iFaceFrm != null)
{
    //use the iFaceFrm or frm here
}
```

**Edit**

The issue with your LINQ statement is declaring the type, the type of a LINQ statement is inferred, so you don't put it in the select:

```
var fr = from item in lsf
         where item.Name == "child1"
         select item;
```

Or, if you want to do it proceduraly:

```
var fr = lsf.Where(f => f.Name == "child1").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Tq the suggested code is correct. I am not sure why the first linq part not functioning properly. I used for the condition to get the form object and it is working fine. can you check the linq I wrote and find out what is the issue please?